# How can I get database design from a existing database

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using `WAMP`. In `phpMyAdmin` I created database without any model (database is pretty simple) and now I need to show structure of database but I do not know how. The closest one I got is Designer tab in `phpMyAdmin`, but there are not relations (look at image). I tried to add them manually but I got error Relation features are disabled. I am not 100% sure but I think my db is already using InnoDB
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your tables uses non-relational engine.

Check the engine for each table with `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` statement. If you do not see `ENGINE=InnoBD` at the end of the script then ater the table's engine with `ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE = InnoDB;`.

Comment: I can now add my relationships. Is there a way I can show relationships that already exist? Some of these tables are generated via Laravel and I don't know what is their relationship